# File download over HTTPS (C#)

Tags: c#, https, download

I have form where user can attach word documents & is saved on SQL DB. Retrieving those documents works flawlessly over http but breaks on https. I'm storing the document in session. Here is my code to retrieve the file:

```
Attachments attach = AttachmentsSession[e.Item.ItemIndex] as Attachments;

string extension = attach.Extension;

byte[] bytFile = attach.AttachmentData;

Response.Clear();

Response.Buffer = true;

if (extension == ".doc")

{

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + attach.Name);

}

else if (extension == ".docx")

{

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-
officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";

    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + attach.Name);

}

Response.Charset = "";

Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

Response.BinaryWrite(bytFile);

HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

Response.End();
```

Again, it works on http but not on https & the document is stored in SQL DB. Please help

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Let me explain again. Users can upload documents no matter it is http or https. but when admins go in the web interface they are not able to download the file which was uploaded by users over https. The above code is to download the file for admins

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving an error message when you try to download over HTTPS?  Does the error only occur while using IE?  If so, try changing the "Do not save Encrypted pages" feature in the 
IE advanced settings.  See the information at the following link: http://www.ureader.com/msg/153060.aspx

Comment: IE throws following error --> "Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later". Even firefox for some reason doesn't know what is the extension of the file and is not able to auto detect its a word file. This is only a concern over https

Comment: Please see the following MS KB article:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431  I would try removing the no-cache header(s) if you can.  If it's explicitly in the page you can just edit it out.  If you need to do it for an entire site or server please refer to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247404